# C++ delete a pointer (free memory)

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

Consider the following code:

```
int a = 10;
int * b = &a;
int * c = b;
delete b; // equivalent to delete c;
```

Am I correct to understand in the last line, `delete b` and `delete c` are equivalent, and that both will free the memory space holding `a`, thus `a` is no longer accessible?

Comment: `a` has not been dynamically allocated, therefore using `delete` on it leads to undefined behaviour. :(

Comment: "thus a is no longer accessible?" It is just undefined behaviour.

Comment: a is created on stack, no need to delete it.

Comment: @juanchopanza *"thus a is no longer accessible?" It is just undefined behaviour.*  Well, `a` won't be accessible after the `SIGSEGV`...

Comment: If we ignore the `delete` of a stack object... If `b` was pointing to a `new` allocated object, yes you are correct that `delete`ing `c` or `b` would be equivalent: both would be pointing to the same `delete`d object

Comment: @AndrewHenle But there doesn't even  have to be a sigsegv.

Comment: "delete b; // equivalent to delete c;" - equivalent or not is irrelevant. You didn't `new` that memory, so `delete`ing it is Undefined Behaviour and your program is thus meaningless.

Comment: @juanchopanza of course not. It's "undefined behaviour", so *anything* could happen - a segfault - or, a call to your mother telling her that you fscked up.. it's all up to the compiler at this point.

Comment: This is why generally `unique_ptr` is better option. There is **only one unique owner**.

Comment: **You do not delete pointers in C++.** You delete objects that were allocated with `new`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The behaviour of your program is *undefined*. You can *only* use `delete` on a pointer to memory that you have allocated using `new`. If you had written

```
int* b = new int;
*b = 10;
int* c = b;
```

then you *could* write *either* `delete b;` *or* `delete c;` to free your memory. Don't attempt to *derefererence* either `b` or `c` after the `delete` call though, the behaviour on doing that is also *undefined*.

Comment: This is also why raw pointers are so dangerous. There is no way to know if dynamically allocated memory that a certain pointer is pointing to was deleted by another pointer pointing to the same memory. And attempting to "check" by dereferencing results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: @GillBates This is why raw *owning* pointers are dangerous.  non owning pointers are fine.

Comment: @NathanOliver If you don't work with smart pointers and you `new` something then you're going to have owning pointers. We hadn't talked about smart pointers here yet, so I wasn't going to bring it up when it comes to the dangers of a raw pointer.

Comment: @GillBates That is true.  I was just correcting your blanket statement.  There is nothing wrong with raw pointers.  There is a lot of things wrong having raw owning pointers.  You can have pointers that do not own anything and those should be used when needed.

Comment: @NathanOliver At that point `weak_ptr` is better than a raw pointer :)

Comment: I do not think so.  In order to have a weak pointer you need a shared pointer somewhere so now you have atomic reference counting.  If I just want to return a element from a container and I want to return `null` if it does not exist then a raw pointer is just fine.  Smart pointers have there place but smart pointers everywhere is not a needed IMHO.

Comment: In the does-not-exist case and if it absolutely has to be a pointer I’d much prefer to return something along the lines of `std::optional<gsl::not_null<T*>>`. That accomplishes the same goal but makes the interface a *lot* more expressive. Users forgetting about or ignoring the possibility of an “empty” return value will be much less likely.

Answer (score 5):

If `b` and `c` point to the same memory then deleting either of them releases the memory so that assumption is correct.  `a` becoming inaccessible is not correct in this case though as you do not point to dynamically allocated memory and you can only call `delete`/`delete[]` on something that was created with `new`/`new[]`.  Trying to `delete`/`delete[]` a pointer that was not allocated with `new`/`new[]` is undefined behavior and will generally end in a segmentation fault.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I said *generally*, not always.  First and foremost it is undefined behavior.  Whatever winds up happening doesn't really matter.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck That is a straw man.  UB does not means the code is going to format your hard drive.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I dislike exceptions.  Instead I prefer encapsulation and use smart pointers when I need owning pointers.  Then there is no worry and no exception overhead unless new throws but at that point there really is nothing to do.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Can it be considered GC, yes.  Is it, it depends.  If you use a [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) it is no more overhead than using raw `new` and `delete` but it is 100% safe unless you try to break it.  a `shared_ptr` is a little more like GC since it ha a reference count but it is granular in that it only applies to the pointer and nothing else in the code.

Answer (score 5):

The confusing part is that the answer to your question

> Am I correct to understand in the last line, delete b and delete c are equivalent"

Is yes, they're equivalent, and both UB as mentioned everywhere else here.

Comment: Hmm, this seems like the beginnings of a philosophical question. The compiler is not required to treat `delete b` and `delete c` the same way, because there are no requirements at all about what it should do if it sees either. So to decide whether they're "equivalent", we have to decide what "equivalent" means . . .

Answer (score 0):

you should never use delete for variable that allocated on stack,
delete is the counterpart of new.
hence no delete/free is needed when no new/alloc is used, once you are out of the "scope" of the code ( in this case the program itself ) all memory is considered available.

Comment: Don't say "stack" - it's not a language concept. Use the term "automatic storage duration" instead, which is defined by the C++ standard.

Comment: Also, you're approaching it from the wrong side. It's also wrong to use delete for variables with static storage duration (such as globals). You can be more precise by stating what you _should_ do_: use `delete` only on pointers returned by `new`. Not even on those returned by `new[]`.