# C++ program Exits when deletes an char array

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-allocation

There is a problem in deleting the elements of my array.
You can see some of my code below.

after second running of `delete[] payload[x].data` at the second `for` loop, the program exits.

```
    struct s_payload{
        u_char data[300];
    }
    .
    .
    u_char sample[300] ="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu mea laudem impetus.";
    int _bufferSizeConnection = 1000;
    int testCounter = 0;
    s_payload* activeBuffer = new s_payload[_bufferSizeConnection];
    for (;;) {
        for (long int counter = 0; counter < _bufferSizeConnection; counter++) {        
            memcpy(activeBuffer[counter].data, sample, 299);
        }
        //_buffersConnection is std::queue
        _buffersConnection.push(activeBuffer);
         testCounter += 1;
        if (testCounter == 15) {
            LOG_INFO(">testcounter %d", testCounter);
            break;
        }            
        activeBuffer = new s_payload[_bufferSizeConnection];                       
    }        
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        //taking one of the activeBuffer from _buffersConnection
        s_payload* payload = _buffersConnection.wait_and_pop();         
        for (int x = 0; x < _bufferSizeConnection; x++) {
            u_char* current= payload[x].data;
            delete[] payload[x].data;   //Exit at the second running of this line;
        }
        delete[] payload;
    }
```

what is wrong with this piece of code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot delete something you did not call new on.  see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40134139/c-delete-a-pointer-free-memory

Comment: @NathanOliver on struct s_payload i declared a fixed size char array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have said `activeBuffer = new s_payload[...]`, so you could legitimately say `delete[] activeBuffer`.  However, `data` is an array, not a pointer, within each `s_payload` element of `activeBuffer`.  Therefore, you don't need to `delete payload[x].data` — whenever you `delete payload[x]` or `delete[] payload`, `data` will also be gone.

However, I would recommend rethinking your approach rather than trying to patch what you have.  You are pushing and popping arrays of fixed-size buffers — is that really necessary?  Could you just push and pop `std::string`s or `std::vector<unsigned char>`s, and not have to worry as much about your memory management?  A `std::vector` can hold an arbitrary amount of data, for example.

Let the library do as much of the work as possible so you won't have to!